# Adding optional debug/verbose output in PHP with minimal footprint

Tags: php, debugging, logging, verbose

Currently I develop a library in PHP. This library uses it's own namespace. To store global (in the scope of the library's namespace) settings I use a static class, similar to this:

```php
class Settings {
    public static $verbose = true;
}
```

To make verbose output easy and adaptable I use a static method like this one:

```php
class Log {
    public static function v($msg) {
        if ( ! Settings::$verbose) { return; }
        echo $msg . "<br>\n";
    }
}
```

This way I can easily add verbose output to my code:

```php
Log::v('Answering questions...');
echo '42';
```

However, this approach creates lot's of unnecessary method calls which return immediately when verbose output is deactivated.

Now I thought about changing my approach in the following way:

```php
class Log {

    public static $v = false;

    public static function init() {
        self::$v = Settings::$verbose;
    }

    public static function v($msg) {
        echo $msg . "<br>\n";
    }

}
```

I copy the value of `Settings::$verbose` to `Log::$v` just because that's shorter. Now - after calling `Log::init()` once - my verbose output line looks like this:

```php
Log::$v && Log::v('All questions answered.');
```

But this line is not as neat/short as simply typing `Log::v('')`. I don't like the idea of having to type `Log::$v && Log::v('')` whenever I want to add information about what's going on.

My question is: Is there another way to add verbose output with a minimal footprint? Are there any inbuilt functions in PHP which I'm not aware of?

To avoid conflicts with other components I want to keep things within the library's namespace, so I don't want to use a global constant like `define('V', true)`.

**Update:** I just recognized that constants can be namespaced, thus I could change my second approach to:

```php
define(__NAMESPACE__ . '\V', true);
V && Log::v('...');
```

But my questions remains...